# How to prevent an exception when canceling an OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I click on the button to upload a photo. When I cancel the photo selection, the program throws an exception.

Here's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Islem.getFileName());
    ımageBox1.Image = img;
}

class Islem
{
    public static string getFileName()
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return ofd.FileName;
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

How to fix this situation?

Comment: "Falls ine wrong place" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: Which wrong place? Can't you correct your code not to go there if dialog cancels?

Comment: How can I prevent an exception when I cancel an openfiledialog?

Comment: Your button click assumes you have a valid file.  You would have to check first.

Comment: What is the exact exception that is thrown? Show the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user cancels the dialog, your `getFileName` function returns an empty string. Therefore, you get an exception when you try to load the image from a path that doesn't exist (i.e., the empty string). If you read the exception message, you would figure it out yourself.

You can do something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string imgFilePath = Islem.getFileName();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgFilePath))
    {
        Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(imgFilePath);
        ımageBox1.Image = img;
    }
}
```

That would only use the file path (i.e., load the image) if the returned string isn't empty.

Alternatively, you can check if the file exists:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(imgFilePath)) { //use it to load the image }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. When I select an image, the dialog window comes up twice. When I select an image, the first one gets the image path and the second one loads the image. But is not it wrong? Is there no other way?

Comment: Oops! My bad, I forgot to reuse the `imgFilePath` variable. Just fixed it.

Comment: I got it. 
Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(imgFilePath);

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Just remember, next time, read the exception message and if you still can't figure out what the problem is, **include the exception in your question**, this is very important. Good luck :)